# how to design a state with ui-router that replaces the content only of index.html with two files and two controllers

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

How to design a state with UI-Router that replaces the CONTENT ONLY of index.html with two files and two controllers.
i have views/dishDetail.html & views/comment.html and 
I`m trying this:

```
  .state('app.dishDetail',{
        url: 'menu/:id',
        views: {
            'content@' : {
                'disComment': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/dishDetail.html',
                    controller  : 'DishDetailController'
                    },
                'myComment': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/comment.html',
                    controller  : 'DishCommentController'
                    }
            }
        }

    });
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the way

```
    .state('app.dishDetail', {
      url: 'menu/:id',
      views: {
        'content@': {
            template: '<div ui-view="disComment" /></div>' + 
            '<div ui-view="myComment" /></div>',
          },
          'disComment@app.dishDetail': {
            templateUrl: 'views/dishDetail.html',
            controller: 'DishDetailController'
          },
          'myComment@app.dishDetail': {
            templateUrl: 'views/comment.html',
            controller: 'DishCommentController'
          }
      }
```

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yBdoOSLAHtQ3aAqLlZqh?p=preview)